# Spring OAuth2 name always null

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

New to OAuth2 and Spring framework. Have followed two introduction guides to it so far (for example [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) one) and the `OAuth2User` object (org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User) always has a null value for the "name" attribute which, as following along with the tutorials, should not be null apparently. Ended up cloning the repo just to make sure I had identical code and value was still null.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Map<String, Object> user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
        
//      for(String key : principal.getAttributes().keySet()) {
//          System.out.println(String.format("key= %s value=%s", key, principal.getAttribute(key)));
//      }
        return Collections.singletonMap("name", principal.getAttribute("name"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                .antMatchers("/", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            )
            .oauth2Login();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }

}

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Uncommenting the for loop above revleals most keys fetched from `principle.getAttributes()` to be null (including *name*, *email* etc). Not clear to me what I'm doing wrong here - I have clientId and clientSecret (obtained by creating github OAuth app) configured correctly in my properties fie. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by access my github profile and update my name (In my case I didn't provide it)!